# Is there any option to change the behaviourwhen we click on dots in React-slick?

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I want to show a notification if a user clicks on any dot and I also want to prevent moving to the next slide if a user clicks on a dot. Is there a good solution to implement this?
Here is the link to react-slick(appendDots example). There you can see the customPaging method. The point is that I want to set up my onClick function to div to change the behavior when the user clicks on a dot. But react-slick puts its onClick, that's why I can't override it.
https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/append-dots

Comment: please post the code on CodeSandbox and share a link writing a paragraph won't help others much in understanding your problem

Comment: @Zein thank you for your comment. I added some description to my question. I just want to find a way to put my own function when user clicks on any dot under the carousel

Comment: I added an answer https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-playground-forked-ijve6d go click on a number and check the console what's left is to find a dot Icon and added in the <li> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something That could help
you can actually append the dots into different components hence you can add a onClick event
example

```
appendDots={
      dots=><ul>
      {dots.map((dot,key)=><li onClick={()=>openNotification(key)}>{yourdot}</li>)}
      </ul>
    }>
```

Default for this prop is: dots =>

  {dots}

Refer to this link for more info [React-Slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/#appendDots)

Comment: Thank you for your help) It works, But is there any opportunity to omit an unsed variable "dot"?

Comment: yes you can assign an icon to an unused variable and use it or put the icon inside the li tag material ui is a great option to select an icon

Comment: To be honest I didn't get your point... Do you mean I can override a variable with an icon? Could you show me please an example?

Comment: @Lenur https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-playground-forked-ijve6d?file=/index.js

Comment: check the link you can use it like the example or even put the icon directly

Comment: You mean that here "dots.map((dot, k) => " I can assign to variable "dot"?

Comment: @Lenur I don't understand your question, I included a link  where I used a custom icon check it please and let me know if you have any question

Comment: I meant a "dot" variable in this string "dots.map((dot, k)" . It is declared, but the value is never read

Comment: @Lenur yeah and I'll explain why. usually, the dot is a component that includes the icon, onclick event, and more we did a map on dots to know the number of images that's it. If you want onclick to go to the slide you need to add the slickGoTo function which takes the index as arg